# LinearLayout performance with layout_weight attribute

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I was trying to design the following view in my photo album app, and I finally did something after I ask that to the StackOverflow.

As I read about layout_weight attribute, when it is used in a nested structure, it may couse some performance problems.

I'm planning to use the following layout for repeated rows by loading while the user slides the screen down.

Here is the layout :

[image]

Here is the code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#1000b0"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#d0b0b0"
                android:textSize="15sp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#b170b0"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#b110b0"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#1070b0"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- The second line  --> 

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#a070b0"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15sp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button12"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#111"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button13"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#b110b0"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button14"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#7510b0"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please note that I put the "button" just for test, they will be ImageView.
I only used LinearLayout. 
Does it the right way to have this view (according to performance) ?

I wrote just 2 rows for now, it is gonna have more rows that are created dynamically on run time later. Does it get slow when the row count reaches, maybe 20 ?

Should I change the apporach to have this view ?

Thanks

Comment: If the row count is 20 then use a `ListView`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

Yes do all ListView see that Lazyadapter from that you can avoid it.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#1000b0"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#d0b0b0"
                android:textSize="15sp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#b170b0"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#b110b0"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#1070b0"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- The second line -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#a070b0"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textSize="15sp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button12"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#111"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button13"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#b110b0"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button14"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#7510b0"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#1000b0"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#d0b0b0"
                android:textSize="15sp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#b170b0"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#b110b0"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#1070b0"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. If there are 20 rows during the life time of the app, does it couse a memory or cpu problem with this ? Because Im planning to add more photos when the user wants to see.

Comment: @anL yes it'll give memoryoutofboundryexception.

Comment: do you have a suggestion for this situation ? :)

Comment: @anL yes do all `ListView` see that `Lazyadapter` from that you can avoid it. Do you need example for lazyadapter with ListView?

Comment: Thanks, I'll google them and do some research again.

Comment: If you are getting memory out of bound Exception , then you have to decode your image, before using it. or you can increase your RAM size of your Emulator.